# Problems while importing external js files to vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a couple external js files and I need them on my HTML file for the website to work properly.

**What I tried:**

I added these imports to main.js:

```
import '../../assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min';
import '../../assets/js/home';
import '../../assets/js/common';
import '../../assets/js/flickity.pkgd';
import '../../assets/js/owl.carousel';
import '../../assets/js/jquery.simplePagination';
import '../../assets/js/zeynep';
```

but when testing in `vue serve` it returns lots of errors or if it ends up compiling the website content stops being displayed.

Is there a way to import js files that use "normal" js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yould simply include script tags for these dependencies in /public/index.html